# Editablegrid mysql binding not updating

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, editablegrid

I am using editablegrid with mysql. It binds and display data to my grid. However when I try to edit or update the grid it fails to do so.

Below is the some of the code of my loaddata,

```
$grid->addColumn('CertificateNo', 'CertificateNo', 'integer', NULL, false); 
$grid->addColumn('ID', 'ID', 'integer');
$grid->addColumn('QuizNo', 'Test No', 'integer');  
$grid->addColumn('Received', 'Received', 'boolean');  
$grid->addColumn('DateReceived', 'Date Received', 'datetime');
```

Below is code for the update script:

```
    // Get all parameters provided by the javascript
$colname = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['colname']));
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['id']));
$coltype = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['coltype']));
$value = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['newvalue']));
$tablename = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['tablename']));
    / This very generic. So this script can be used to update several tables.
$return=false;
if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$tablename." SET ".$colname." = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("si",$value, $id);
    $return = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

Below is the part of javascript which passes the value to my update.php script.

```
    function updateCellValue(editableGrid, rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row, onResponse)
{      
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            tablename : editableGrid.name,
            id: editableGrid.getRowId(rowIndex), 
            newvalue: editableGrid.getColumnType(columnIndex) == "boolean" ? (newValue ? 1 : 0) : newValue, 
            colname: editableGrid.getColumnName(columnIndex),
            coltype: editableGrid.getColumnType(columnIndex)            
        },
        success: function (response) 
        { 
            // reset old value if failed then highlight row
            var success = onResponse ? onResponse(response) : (response == "ok" || !isNaN(parseInt(response))); // by default, a sucessfull reponse can be "ok" or a database id 
            if (!success) editableGrid.setValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue);
            highlight(row.id, success ? "ok" : "error"); 
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, exception) { alert("Ajax failure\n" + errortext); },
        async: true
    });
```

This template came with a javascript editablegrid-2.0.1. I noticed the problem has to do with primary key. In the demo which can be found from www.editablegrid.net the table has primary key ID whereas mine has CertificateNo but ID in my table is not a primary key.

So I changed the

```
$grid->addColumn('ID', 'ID', 'integer', NULL, false);
```

to

```
$grid->addColumn('CertificateNo', 'CertificateNo', 'integer', NULL, false);
```

Now I can not update the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you could see this code in loaddata.php

```
$grid->addColumn('action', 'Action', 'html', NULL, false, 'id');
```

replace 'id' at the last column with 'CertificateNo' and it will be like this

```
$grid->addColumn('action', 'Action', 'html', NULL, false, 'CertificateNo');
```

And then reload your page to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

update.php uses $_POST['id'] maybe you should change that to $_POST['CertificateNo'] and proccess the id as just another column since it's no longer the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to change in js/demo.js in

```
function DatabaseGrid() 
{ 
    this.editableGrid = new EditableGrid("HERE!!! Chage to name of your sql table", {...
```

and also rename your `CertificateNo` to "id" or make new before it, because the grid works with it on many places, so it's hard to change everywhere.